# MATLAB CODE Rectification

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The below code is not running in matlab. I am trying an anonymous function in matlab.Can you pls tell me whats wrong in this line :

```
Inv_Y_Quant = blockproc(BB,[8 8], InvQuant);
```

and the related code is below:

```
clear all
clc

I = imread('cameraman.tif');
% convert it to double
I = im2double(I);
% "Trim by 128"
I = I-128;
% Generate the DCT matrix
T = dctmtx(8);
% Generate Function handler for DCT
MyFun1 = @(block_struct) T * block_struct.data * T';
% BlockProcess the DCT the function for 8 by 8 blocks
B = blockproc(I,[8 8],MyFun1);
% Form the Quantization matrix
Q = [ 16 11 10 16 24 40 51 61
12 12 14 19 26 58 60 55
14 13 16 24 40 57 69 56
14 17 22 29 51 87 80 62
18 22 37 56 68 109 103 77
24 35 55 64 81 104 113 92
49 64 78 87 103 121 120 101
72 92 95 98 112 100 103 99];
% now generate function handler for the quantization
MyFun2 = @(block_struct)block_struct.data ./Q;
% perform the quantization
BB = blockproc(B,[8 8],MyFun2);
InvQuant = @(block_struct)round(block_struct.data.*Q);
Inv_Y_Quant = blockproc(BB,[8 8], InvQuant);
InvDct = @(block_struct)dct_matrix'*block_struct.data*dct_matrix;
Z = blockproc(Inv_Y_Quant, [8 8], InvDct);
Z = Z+128;
figure, imshow(Z)
Z = uint8(Z);
figure, imshow(Z)

%imwrite(Z, 'Mar7.tif');
%b = imread('Mar7.tif');
%imshow(b)
```

Comment: what is the error Matlab gives you? what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The cause of the error was:

Undefined function or variable 'dct_matrix'.

Error in ==>
@(block_struct)dct_matrix'*block_struct.data*dct_matrix


Error in ==> blockprocFunDispatcher at 14
        output_block = fun(block_struct);

Error in ==> blockprocInMemory at 71
[ul_output fun_nargout] =
blockprocFunDispatcher(fun,block_struct,...

Error in ==> blockproc at 248
    result_image =
    blockprocInMemory(a,block_size,fun,border_size,...

Error in ==> matlab5 at 31
Z = blockproc(Inv_Y_Quant, [8 8], InvDct);

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote in your comment, the problem is that you try to use array `dct_matrix` in anonymous function `InvDct`. This array was **never** defined in your code.

Did you meant to use matrix `T` (init as `dctmtx(8)`)?

**edit:**
When using parameters in anonymous functions (as `dct_matrix` in this example), these parameters should be defined before the anonymous function is defined.

Comment: can u pls tell me whr and hw shld i define tht array??    Thanks

Comment: I am not a language purist, but what about writing standard english and not street chunks?